# How to change x axis interval using matplotlib, when strings are used?

Tags: python, string, matplotlib, axis, intervals

I have a dataframe 'roads' that I'm plotting this way (so a graph with dots):

`ax = roads.plot(x='Link_no', y='Road_quality_index', style='o')`

The x-axis are link numbers in the form of strings (these are road segment number). Now, python automatically leaves away som of these strings (9 out of 10) to keep it readable. However, I want to show even less x axis points, only about 1 out of 20.

Online, most people refer to using plt.yticks. However, this is only possible when you are using ints or floats I believe.

Can someone help us out?

Comment: Internally, the categorical ticks are numbered `0,1,2,3,... `. So `plt.yticks(range(0, 100, 10)` would skip 9 out of 10 ticks.

Answer (score 0):

You can get your current ticks, resample them, and set the sparse list as your new ticks. Below as an example, I sample by checking mod(index(a),20)==0, which is true for 1 label in every 20 labels.

```
# current x labels
current_ticks = ax.get_xticklabels()
# resampling every other label, change mod(20) to sample less
custom_ticks = [a.get_text() for a in current_ticks if current_ticks.index(a)%20==0] 
# set as new labels
ax.set_xticks(custom_ticks)
ax.set_xticklabels(custom_ticks)
```